# How to install Canon IP2770 printer on elementary OS?

Tags: drivers

I have to install my printer for my school works. Thanks.

Comment: The printer family IP2700 have driver for Ubuntu and derivates in Canonical repositories. So you can installing it from Configuration -> Printers -> Add new printer

Comment: http://www.driverlook.com/download/4028/canon-pixma-ip2770-ip2772-printer-driver-linux-debian/

Comment: @bitseater That seems like an answer to me.

Comment: Right @Lewis Goddard.  i add it

Answer (score 1):

The printer family IP2700 have driver for Ubuntu and derivates in Canonical repositories. So you can installing it from Configuration -> Printers -> Add new printer